# Sending rsyslog messages to remote file system

Tags: ubuntu, network-share, rsyslog, syslog

I have an Ubuntu server that will be running `rsyslog` and many "client" devices and applications sending logs to it (via various syslog clients).

I know that `rsyslog` logs everything to `/var/log`, but ideally I could "*pump*" these logs to a file on another machine. Effectively making the server where `rsyslog` lives as a centralized location for clients to send log messages to, but allowing me to send the logs to a network drive or a machine with a considerably larger storage capability.

Is this possible to do? I know `rsyslog` has a lot of modules that you can plug in, but I don't see any that allow you to override `/var/log` in favor of a remote file location. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you can set a `rsyslog` [server](https://www.tecmint.com/install-rsyslog-centralized-logging-in-centos-ubuntu/) and `rsyslog` [clients](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-rsyslog-client-to-send-logs-to-rsyslog-server-in-centos-7/).
Server

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

To use TCP connection (which is slower but more reliable), search and uncomment the lines below.

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

Set template for remote logs:

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs 
& ~
```

restart syslog.

For clients:

```
*. *  @192.168.10.254:514
```

Configure where to send logs.

And do not forget to restart the `rsyslog`

Comment: Thanks @Romeo (+1) -- when you say "_Configure where to send logs._" can you please explain how this is accomplished? Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, this is client config. You define to which host and port to send logs.

Comment: Thanks, I assume I would do this in the server's `/var/conf/syslog.ini` file? Something like `send.logs=<host>:<port>/some/path/to/logfile.log` maybe?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, for servers are first two lines. (port and template). You can check links for more detailed info.

Comment: OK thanks again. I guess I don't fully understand the "flow" of syslog/rsyslog then. My _understanding_ is that the flow of log messages would go `clients --> server --> logfile`, no? If that's the case, and if I want the server to write logs to another machine, then I'm not understanding how something like "`UDPServerRun 514`" would send logs to, say, `<host>:<port>/some/path/to/logfile.log`. Am I missing something big here? Thanks again, I'm honestly not trying to be difficult, I'm just not seeing the "forest through the trees!"

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, this define how the server will listen (`UDPServerRun 514`), `template` define how the files (on server) will be named

Comment: Thank you! Two last followup questions, if you don't mind. **(1)** If I wanted to make a change to the `rsyslog` server config (change the value of the `%HOSTNAME%` its writing to, etc.), I have to restart it, correct? If so, what will happen to the log messages coming from clients while the server is restarting? Will they be lost? Is there a way to restart `rsyslog` with the new configuration such that log messages sent by clients are not lost during the restart? And **(2)** is it possible to configure `rsyslog` to route different log messages to different log files based on certain criteria?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, the idea of this site is: one question+answers. So please open new questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/ask

Comment: Apologies @Romeo! For reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/1105896/configuring-rsyslog-not-to-drop-messages-while-restarting and https://serverfault.com/questions/1105897/configuring-rsyslog-to-route-messages-to-different-log-files-based-on-content