# Configuring rsyslog to route messages to different log files based on content

Tags: rsyslog, syslog

Can `rsyslog` be configured to route log messages to different log files/locations based on the content of the log message? If so, how and could I see a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of such option (to filter the messages and send to different places, based on content).

Based on your questions maybe you want to take a look on Splunk. This is (kind of) log storage, indexing and filtering system. You store logs and then you define filters what you want to see, draw graphics, create statistics and so on. Also this software do not send logs (client) if the server is not available.